# The doPost function is executed twice (google apps script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I hope for your help, since the problem is non-standard for me and I could not solve it after many attempts.

### Problem

I have a standard function for receiving POST requests and she it works stably on small volumes, sample code:

```
let sheet = SpreadSheet.getSheetByName("name")
let dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "dd.MM.yyy HH:mm:ss") // Moscow time
<...>
function doPost(e) {
    sheet.insertRowBefore(2) // adds a line before the second one
    sheet.getRange(2, 1).setValue(e.parameter.par1)
    sheet.getRange(2, 2).setValue(dateTime)
    sheet.getRange(2, 3).setValue(e.parameter.par2)
    sheet.getRange(2, 4).setValue(e.parameter.par3)
    sheet.getRange(2, 5).setValue(e.parameter.par4)
}
```

In the table it looks like this: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWmjR.png)

In essence, the function must be executed synchronously and work stably, but when the function receives a lot of requests (about 140 in 1-10 seconds), it can create two rows at once and write data twice to the same second row. As a result, for 140 queries, there are ~4 empty rows in the table, the data from which was lost

This is how an empty string added by mistake looks like: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6lov.png)

### Attempt to solve

To prevent two scripts from running simultaneously, I used the LockService function from google apps script, my code began to look like this:

```
let sheet = SpreadSheet.getSheetByName("name")
let dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "dd.MM.yyy HH:mm:ss") // Moscow time
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock() // LockService
<...>
function doPost(e) {
  if (lock.tryLock(30000)) { // waiting for a queue 30 seconds
    sheet.insertRowBefore(2) // adds a line before the second one
    sheet.getRange(2, 1).setValue(e.parameter.par1)
    sheet.getRange(2, 2).setValue(dateTime)
    sheet.getRange(2, 3).setValue(e.parameter.par2)
    sheet.getRange(2, 4).setValue(e.parameter.par3)
    sheet.getRange(2, 5).setValue(e.parameter.par4)
    lock.releaseLock() // unblocking
  }
}
```

I tried different queue waiting times, but it didn't lead to success. The function continued to leave empty lines

**I ask for your help, as I have been puzzling over this problem for a long time. What to do? I will be grateful for any information**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to do [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) before `setValue`

Comment: Thanks!! This helped, the only thing is that I put `flush()` not only before `setValue`, but also after

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `flush()` I'd recommend to replace this:

```
// 5 calls (get/set) to server
sheet.getRange(2, 1).setValue(e.parameter.par1)
sheet.getRange(2, 2).setValue(dateTime)
sheet.getRange(2, 3).setValue(e.parameter.par2)
sheet.getRange(2, 4).setValue(e.parameter.par3)
sheet.getRange(2, 5).setValue(e.parameter.par4)
```

with this:

```
// 1 call (get/set) to the server
sheet.getRange(2,1,2,5).setValues([ 
  e.parameter.par1,
  dateTime,
  e.parameter.par2, 
  e.parameter.par3,
  e.parameter.par4
])
```

Best Practices: [Batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices?hl=en#use_batch_operations)

Comment: Thank you for your edit, it really improved the structure of the code, and also helped in solving the problem